# jquerymobile compact listview css

Tags: css, listview, jquery-mobile

The current listview I'm using has extra space above and below the texts. How do I make it a really compact one? http://jsfiddle.net/qW6sP/8/

```
       <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">            
        <li>
                <h6 style='font-size:8pt;'>Mode: repairing</h6>
                <p>00 hours 00 mins 00 secs</p>                    
                <p class="ui-li-aside"><a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" id="dismissbtn" onclick="fadeint()" data-mini="true" >Done</a></p>

        </li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space is created by the **h6** and **p** tags. Use a custom span class and then you can position and size the text however you want...

html:

> ```
> <span class="compactHeader"> Mode: repairing </span>
> <span class="compactText">00 hours 00 mins 00 secs</span>
> ```

css:

```
.compactHeader
{
  //set size and positioning as you want.
}

.compactText
{
  //set size and positioning as you want
}
```